# execute PAF scripts in a pipeline in GIT Lab

Tags: ipaf, paceautomationframework

I create a project in git lab. I'm trying to use pipelines . Is it possible to execute PAF scripts in a pipeline in GIT Lab?

Answer (score 0):

**Yes,** you can configure PAF scripts execution in a GitLab pipeline.